# Scraping timestamp data on comments from Reddit page with BeautifulSoup doesn't return anything

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, request, reddit

I am trying to scrape the timestamps of all comments in a Reddit thread for research purposes. As of right now, the post has about 700 total comments. So I thought the best way to scrape this data without using existing apps or extensions would be through SOUP. Below is the beginnings of the python program I'm writing for this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/NewTubers/comments/1bfhcwz/feedback_friday_post_your_videos_here_if_you_want/"
r = requests.get(url)
#print(r.status_code) returned 200

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser') #lxml didn't work either
#print(soup.title) returned the correct title of the HTML page
file = open("scraped_timestamps.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(file)
writer.writerow(["TIMESTAMPS"])

timestamps = soup.findAll('a', class_='_3yx4Dn0W3Yunucf5sVJeFU')
for timestamp in timestamps:
    writer.writerow([timestamp.text])
file.close()
```

When one inspects the timestamps on comments, they all have this one same class "3yx4Dn0W3Yunucf5sVJeFU" under the attribute "a". So, targeting this exact class, I tried to print out the timestamp text. This didn't return anything so I'm quite confused. I have tried using lxml but I didn't work either.

Also, Reddit shows you the exact time down to the second when you hover over the timestamp text. I'd like to possibly scrape that data as well in the future but for now I'm simply trying to scrape the generic timestamp text on comments.

Comment: *Always and first of all, take a look at your response/soup to see if all the expected ingredients are in place.* You will not find the expected elements there, because they are loaded and rendered dynamically by JavaScript. Try to use the API or mimic a browser with e.g. `selenium`  (watch out for `shadow-root`) to get the rendered source

Comment: Reddit still offers that same data as *JSON* -- replace that last `/` with `.json` and you dont need BS at all and the data that you are looking for is most likely in that json object.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I've been reading up a bit and also took @rasjani 's suggestion to look at the JSON data. The only possible references to "time" I could find in the data are attributes called "created_utc", since I think it might stand for Coordinated Universal Time. However, the numbers following this attribute are still kind of mysterious to me. Here's an example value: 1710541547.0. No luck trying to decode it so far. I'll look into the Reddit API too if that's a possible route because it seems like the JSON object doesn't load everything on the page.

Comment: 1710541547 is unix timestamp which  is Friday, March 15, 2024 10:25:47 PM in GMT. You can convert value into a datetime via `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1710541547)`

Comment: I see thank you very much for the insight. That's the timestamp data sorted out. I will come back later with the finished code! This has been some good practice for me.

Answer (score 0):

OP here. I've reached an offline solution for now. It became very clear how to get the timestamps I wanted once I installed JSONvue on my browser and saw the structure of the JSON data. Excuse any inefficiencies as the timestamp data was quite nested.

It's also obvious that retrieving the JSON by putting .json at the end the url did not give me the data of every single main comment in the post as it is probably dynamically loaded by Javascript as someone pointed out. I have experimented with requesting HTML as well as json from the URL itself, but it will fail half of the time and return with a data structure that is incompatible with my current code. In either case however, the data still seems to be a fraction of what exists. I will further explore this exercise with how I can get the data of all comments

Here is the code:

```
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import requests
import json
import csv
import datetime

data = open('Reddit.json')
html_json = json.load(data)
file = open("scraped_timestamps.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(file)
writer.writerow(["TIMESTAMPS"])
#print(html.status_code)

parent = html_json[1]['data']['children']
timestamps = []

for i in parent:
    if 'created_utc' in i['data']:
        timestamps.append(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(i['data]['created_utc']))
    else:
        break

sorted_timestamps = sorted(timestamps)
for x in sorted_timestamps:
    writer.writerow([x])
file.close()

#html_json[0] contains the post itself without the comment section
#html_json[1] contains the entire comment section
#I had to check for the existence of the timestamp data, otherwise the query throws
#an error passing the list as html_json[1] also contains the footer without such timestamp data
```